# Spectral Measures: Multi Version (II)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This question is only Q&A!*

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a normal operator:
$$N:\mathcal{D}(N)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

And its spectral measure:
$$E:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad N=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}E(\lambda)$$

Suppose one has:
$$\varphi_0\in\mathcal{H}:\quad\mathcal{H}=\overline{\langle\{E(A)\varphi_0:A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\}\rangle}$$

Denote for shorthand:
$$\nu_0:=\nu_{\varphi_0}(A)=\|E(A)\varphi_0\|^2$$

> Then one has:
>   $$M_\mathrm{id}:\mathcal{D}(M_\mathrm{id})\to\mathcal{L}^2(\nu_0):\quad VM_\mathrm{id}=NV$$

How can I prove this?

**Reference**

This is a prep-up for: [Multi Version (III)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1337158/79762)

Comment: This thread deals with the more precise reducibility of normal unbounded operators instead of cyclicity. *(For further details see: Reducing Spaces)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unitary Map**

Construct the map:
$$V:\mathcal{L}^2(\nu_0)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad Vh:=h(N)\varphi_0$$

By Borel calculus:
$$h\in\mathcal{L}^2(\nu_0):\quad\|h(N)\varphi_0\|^2=\int|h|^2\mathrm{d}\nu_0$$

Especially one has:
$$V\chi_A=E(A)\varphi_0:\quad\mathcal{H}=\overline{\{V\chi_A:A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\}}$$

Concluding unitarity.

**Multiplication**

Remind that it holds:
$$f(N)g(N)\subseteq(fg)(N)$$

Observe also that:
$$h\in\mathcal{L}^2(\nu_0)\iff\varphi_0\in\mathcal{D}h(N)$$

Then one checks:
$$NVh=Nh(N)\varphi_0=(\mathrm{id}h)(N)\varphi_0=V(\mathrm{id}h)=VM_\mathrm{id}h$$

Concluding equivalence.